# Where are the source files for forge?

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When I try to open `Block.class`, or any other classes from the same package as `Block.class`, eclipse will say: "the source attachment does not contain the source for the `Block.class`. You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below:"

What did I do wrong? Where's the source code then?

Also, when I type "extends Block", and hover my cursor over the word "Block" this appears:

> net.minecraft.init.Blocks
>
> Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Comment: I highly doubt that Minecraft source code is available anywhere.  You won't find source to attach in your IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Just do`gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` in your forge folder and you will be able to see the source code (as long as you're working with forge 1.7+). Any way as far as I know your mod will run anyway without having the source attached, but sometimes it helps a lot to see minecraft source code.

Comment: gradlew setupDecompWorkspace is not available any longer.

Comment: @AndersLindén It's almost a year late, and maybe you already discovered this. You can use the *eclipse* task to decompile the sources and then find them in a jar hidden in a cache directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the source for Minecraft Forge at [the Minecraft Forge github repository.](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge) However, the minecraft source code is private, so you have to decompile it yourself with `./gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace`

Comment: How do you do that now, when gradlew setUpDecompWorkspace is not any longer available?

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer a direct task that will decompile Minecraft with Forge for Minecraft 1.14. You can cause the sources to be generated by running the *eclipse* task.

First, make sure the *eclipse* plugin is applied in *build.gradle*:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

Next, run the *eclipse* task and let it run:

```bash
./gradlew eclipse
```

Now the Minecraft sources should be in an *output.jar* located at:

- Linux:

  ```
  ~/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/minecraft_user_repo/mcp/<MC VERSION>-<TIMESTAMP>/joined/patch/output.jar
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  C:\Users\<USER>\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\minecraft_user_repo\mcp\<MC VERSION>-<TIMESTAMP>\joined\patch\output.jar
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Forge never decompiles the Minecraft sources, in versions for 1.6.4 and earlier it included [MCP (Minecraft Coder Pack)](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/download.php?list.2) which decompiled the sources for you, however there has not been a MCP version for 1.7.2 and as such Forge for 1.7.2 and later does not include it.

Answer (score -2):

Dude:
In eclipse, click in Referenced Libraries,

- right click in the first librarie (forgeBin-1.7.10-10.13.2.1230.jar or something like that),
- click on Properties, select External Location and paste this C:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.7.2-10.12.0.1049/forgeSrc-1.7.2-10.12.0.1049-sources.jar(of course, chage "USERNAME" with the real name you have in your computer)
- Click Apply and then OK and its done.
  If that doesnt work, try finding the correct path for your forgeSrc-1.7.2-10.12.0.1049-sources.jar file in your pc and paste it in the External Location.